# How do I use Inheritence in Models in Angular2 using TypeScript?

Tags: angular, typescript

Hi I have a Model Class Question and a ModelClass TrueFalseQuestion, The Field are as following

question.model.ts

```
export class Question {
    answerId: number;
    questionTitle: string;
    questionDescription: string;
```

}

truefalsequestion.model.ts

```
export class TrueFalseQuestion {
    answer: boolean;
```

}

I want to inherit members from Question model to TrueFalseQuestion model.
How do I achieve so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `extends` keyword. Also be sure to import `Question` from question.model.ts

```
export class TrueFalseQuestion extends Question {
    answer: boolean;
}
```